# Selecting an active scala console in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, console, ide

After opening a scala console in IntelliJ Idea you can use "send selection to scala console" (default hot-key CTRL+SHIFT+X). So far so good.

However, if I open a second scala console I can't send selections to the first console anymore, no matter what. The first console is still working if I type to it directly, only sending code-selections to it is the problem.

It seems that if I have multiple consoles open the commands are always sent to the most recently opened one.

**Is there a way to select the "Active" console where the selections are sent if I have multiple consoles open?**

I have tried:

1) Closing the most recently opened console (In this case I can't send selections to any console anymore until I open a new one)

2) Selecting different consoles tabs to be "on the top" (In this case the selections are still sent to the most recent one).

Thanks for the help.